# Mongoose query with OR comparison of nested objects returns an empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with a structure like this:

```
{
    _id
    someParamA,
    someParamB,
    someParamC: {
        nestedParamA,
        nestedParamB,
        nestedParamC,
    }
}
```

what I'm trying to do is query the DB and return all records that have one of a view different values for someParamC.

For example, the query would be something like:

WHERE (someParamC: { nestedParamA: 1, nestedParamB: 1, nestedParamC: 1}) OR (someParamC: { nestedParamA: 1, nestedParamB: 1, nestedParamC: 2}

I've tried this with code like:

```
Collection.find().or([{someParamC: {...}}, {someParamC: {...}}]
```

Which, per the Mongoose debugging messages produces a query like this:

```
{
  "dbQuery": {
    "coll":  "collectionName","method":"find","query": {"$or":[{"someParamC":{...}},{"someParamC":{...}]},"doc":{"sort":{"updatedAt":-1},"projection":{}}
  }
}
```

Which is exactly what I would expect it to be. Even though the collection has multiple matching documents, Mongoose is always returning [].

I have also tried putting the filter inside the .find() method as { $or:  } to no avail. This all also failed when calling .findOne(). Am I doing something wrong here? My specific code, collection, and logging are as follows:

```
cacheResult = await resultsCollection.find()
  .or(<array of parameters, see below>)
  .sort({ updatedAt: -1 });
```

the array of parameters looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "requestParameters":{
      "action":"product",
      "domainId":1,
      "ASIN":"B0763ZCH7K",
      "offers":true,
      "rating":true
    }
  },
  {
    "requestParameters":{
      "action":"product",
      "domainId":1,
      "ASIN":"B0763ZCH7K",
      "offers":true,
      "rating":false
    }
  },
  {
    "requestParameters":{
      "action":"product",
      "domainId":1,
      "ASIN":"B0763ZCH7K",
      "offers":false,
      "rating":true
    }
  },
  {
    "requestParameters":{
      "action":"product",
      "domainId":1,
      "ASIN":"B0763ZCH7K",
      "offers":false,
      "rating":false
    }
  }
]
```

Which generates this request (Mongoose debugging information):

```
{
  "dbQuery":{
    "coll":"public.keepas",
    "method":"find",
    "query":{
      "$or":[
        {
          "requestParameters":{
            "action":"product",
            "domainId":1,
            "ASIN":"B0763ZCH7K",
            "offers":true,
            "rating":true
          }
        },
        {
          "requestParameters":{
            "action":"product",
            "domainId":1,
            "ASIN":"B0763ZCH7K",
            "offers":true,
            "rating":false
          }
        },
        {
          "requestParameters":{
            "action":"product",
            "domainId":1,
            "ASIN":"B0763ZCH7K",
            "offers":false,
            "rating":true
          }
        },
        {
          "requestParameters":{
            "action":"product",
            "domainId":1,
            "ASIN":"B0763ZCH7K",
            "offers":false,
            "rating":false
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "doc":{
      "sort":{
        "updatedAt":-1
      },
      "projection":{

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns [], even though, this is in the database:
[Screen shot of some DB records that should match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozmxi.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have verified that the order of parameters in the sub-document are the same as they appear in the query, and I have tested the query generated by Mongoose in Mongo shell, and the query is working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Mongoose, I was passing in an object for the OR clause that had an undefined parameter. Though this parameter did not appear in the Mongoose debugging output (i.e. it was not included in the query string at all), removing the parameter magically fixed the problem, and the query is working as expected now.